# How to create your own module based on laravel's authentication?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new to laravel and currently i am learning and experimenting on my old php based mini-project conecpt ,i have successfully created the user registration and user login with some features for users,but i am confused how do i create a admin module and provide admin privilege's along with one more sub module (moderator).

[image: Detailed explanation]

I have completed website module,it works fine but i am confused how do i give the following functionalities.

- how do i add admin module
- admin can access user information
- only admin can add moderator

any suggestions would be helpful,
Thank you.

Comment: Can't understand what is it that you want to achieve :/

Comment: how do i build admin side with privileges to add or remove user

Comment: if you can't be more specific on what have you tried or what is your problem don't expect to be helped :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is make some routes only accessible by an admin or moderator?

Make a custom middleware so only if a user has a sufficient role level they can acces the given route.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware

You could have a moderator middleware that checks if a user has role 1 or higher, and a admin middleware that checks if a user has role 2.

i hope this is somewhat what you are searching for.